# Get key and value of JSON from http response using java in build functions

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Need help to find a way in Java to get value from JSON response.

Below is the response received from http request:

```
{"code":"0","content":"{\"Name\":\"Subhajit\"}"}

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
...
...
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new StringReader(jsonInString));
JsonNode innerNode = rootNode.get("content");
System.out.println(innerNode);
```

output: "{"Name":"Subhajit"}"

My Question is :

> How to get the value for Name from the **json in double quotes** without doing any replace string
> manipulation and adding external jars ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You're almost there!*

The innerNode is of type JsonNode. When you use it in a `System.out.println(...)` the method `toString()` is called, to represent the instance.

```
JsonNode innerNode = rootNode.get("content");
System.out.println(innerNode);
```

This returns `"{\"Name\":\"Subhajit\"}"`
Where you would like to see `{"Name":"Subhajit"}`

Use the method `getTextValue()`, on the innerNode instance, and you'll be getting exactly that!

```
System.out.println(innerNode.getTextValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{"code":"0","content":"{\"Name\":\"Subhajit\"}"}

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
...
...
JsonNode rootNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new StringReader(jsonInString));
JsonNode innerNode = rootNode.get("content");
System.out.println(innerNode.getTextValue());
```